# How can I do multiple insert using TOAD?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, toad

I'm trying to do multiple insert in TOAD. The query below executes just fine (the bar below shows that commit has been done), but when I check the database there are no new values. What am I doing wrong?

The query:

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO db1.t1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
VALUES ('blah', 'Answer', 'Y', 'Y', 5)
INTO db1.t1 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
VALUES ('blah', '# answers', 'Y', 'Y', 6)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put semi columns after each statement.

Then use option run as script from tool bar.

Comment: 'Execute as script' has done the job without me changing the query in any way, thanks for the help.